# Kubectl error: memcache.go:265] couldn’t get current server API group list: Get

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

I'm currently facing an issue with my Kubernetes clusters and need some assistance. Everything was running smoothly until today. However, after performing an update on my Ubuntu system, I'm unable to establish a connection from my working environment to the kubernetes clusters.

When executing the command `kubectl get pods`, I'm encountering the following error message:

`E0805 09:59:45.750534  234576 memcache.go:265] couldn’t get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:3334/api?timeout=32s": EOF`

Here are the details of my cluster setup: Kubernetes 1.27, bare-metal, Host System is Ubuntu 20.04

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```bash
kubectl get nodes -v=10
```

and look for the errors.

Comment: Thank you. after that command, I realised I have some DNS issues and after fixing that, I was able to use kubectl again.

Answer (score 7):

It's an authentication issue - to API
ensure kubeconfig exists and corrects from which user command is executed.

This is usually observed while bootstrapping a cluster and forgetting to run below.

```bash
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Comment: This only works on the master node?

Comment: Still have the same error!

Answer (score 4):

- I had the same error, this is because kubectl can't find a cluster information to connect to.

  ```
   E0929 09:47:46.255639   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
   E0929 09:47:46.256923   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
   E0929 09:47:46.258847   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
   E0929 09:47:46.260367   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
   E0929 09:47:46.262189   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
  ```

  - Test using kubectl config view and it should return empty configurations

    ````
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters: null
    contexts: null
    current-context: ""
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users: null```
    ````

  Solution:

  - Configure a cluster manually or install minikube which will configure a single cluster node using any hypervisor or docker
    N.B: Requried to have a hypervisor eg: VirtualBox or Docker installed
  - Follow minikube installation and start minkube https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

  ````
      * minikube v1.31.2 on Darwin 12.6.8
      * Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: hyperkit, virtualbox, ssh
      * Using Docker Desktop driver with root privileges
      * Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
      * Pulling base image ...
      * Downloading Kubernetes v1.27.4 preload ...
          > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  393.21 MiB / 393.21 MiB  100.00% 2.96 Mi
          > gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase...:  447.62 MiB / 447.62 MiB  100.00% 2.96 Mi
      * Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=1986MB) ...
      * Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...
        - Generating certificates and keys ...
        - Booting up control plane ...
        - Configuring RBAC rules ...
      * Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
      * Verifying Kubernetes components...
        - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
      * Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
      * Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
      rako@Karims-MacBook-Air TestBeds & Apps % minikube status
      minikube
      type: Control Plane
      host: Running
      kubelet: Running
      apiserver: Running
      kubeconfig: Configured```
  ````
- Test again and the environment details should return some information not empty as before

  ````
    ```kubectl config view 
    apiVersion: v1
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority: /Users/rako/.minikube/ca.crt
        extensions:
        - extension:
            last-update: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 10:13:33 CEST
            provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
            version: v1.31.2
          name: cluster_info
        server: https://127.0.0.1:64784
      name: minikube
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: minikube
        extensions:
        - extension:
            last-update: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 10:13:33 CEST
            provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
            version: v1.31.2
          name: context_info
        namespace: default
        user: minikube
      name: minikube
    current-context: minikube
    kind: Config
    preferences: {}
    users:
    - name: minikube
      user:
        client-certificate: /Users/rako/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
        client-key: /Users/rako/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key```
  ````

Answer (score 4):

You can also check minikube status and ensure that it's running. I have seen the same error when it fails to come up.

minikube start

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Update your .kube config file again, it will fix the issue..

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region us-east-1 --name EKS_TF_Cluster --profile gkn
```

Comment: you should expand your answer, format the code with a code block. what is the reason for the update in the kubeconfig to remove the memcache.go error?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The original post doesn't relate AWS's managed EKS, but, it seems, to Kubernetes running on Ubuntu. This command would have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error as depicted in the provided screenshot.

[image]

Executing the 'kubectl config view' command reveals that there are no clusters, contexts, or users configured in my Kubernetes configuration file. This lack of configuration implies that my kubectl command won't function correctly, as it lacks the necessary information to connect to a Kubernetes cluster.

[image]

By exporting my KUBECONFIG, I resolved the issue. In Kubernetes, the KUBECONFIG environment variable designates the location of the Kubernetes configuration file. This file holds details about clusters, contexts, and user credentials, enabling tools such as kubectl to communicate with Kubernetes clusters effectively.

[image]

To make the KUBECONFIG environment variable persistent across sessions, you can add the export command to your shell's profile configuration file. This ensures that the variable is set every time you start a new shell session.

- Open your shell's profile configuration file. This file could be ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, or similar, depending on your shell.
- Add the export command to the file, specifying the path to your Kubernetes configuration file:
- Save the file and exit the editor.
- To apply the changes, either restart your shell session or run the "source ~/.bashrc" command in your terminal:

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error after restarting my nodes. I noticed my containerd was disabled using `sudo systemctl status containerd`

To fix this, I restarted the containerd `sudo systemctl restart containerd`

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens because of 2 reasons:

1. Either connection to the wrong GKE cluster so verify the credentials.
2. `.kube/config` is cached and needs to be cleaned if the GKE cluster details have changed.

   `set KUBECONFIG=C:\\$USER_HOME\google-cloud-cli-418.0.0-windows-x86_64\google-cloud-sdk\\.kube\config`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem when I had to connect to a new cluster for which I changed my config file and added credentials for the new cluster in the config file. I retried after deleting the cache folder (in .kube) and now the command  works.

```
cd .kube  
rm  -r cache     # delete the cache folder
```

Answer (score 1):

it works simply by running the following two cmd
`$ sudo swapoff -a`

`$ sudo systemctl start kubelet.service`

Answer (score 1):

check whether the kubectl proxy is running on correct port, From the error "E0929 09:47:46.255639   47147 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" I see its listening on 8080, So expose kubectl proxy on port=8080.

Command:
kubectl proxy --port=8080

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after deleting a cluster with k3d, what I forgot in my local is that I work there with minikube: so I just created a minikube and that's it:

```
minikube start
```

Answer (score 1):

In short summary, due to unexpected latencies stemming from cache invalidation I mistakenly thought my podman/minikube setup is broken again. I reinstalled everything. this time minikube did not work. I thought it's a versions issues, tried many combos, nothing worked. I tried rolling back `podman`, `qemu`, `kubectl` and got no progress. Eventually I tried without podman driver and it works using qemu driver. It also works if I specify podman driver and containerd runtime. Wasted 12 hours to find this. Over 25 reinstalls. Thanks to @osiler for sharing the  `--container-runtime=containerd` flag

Full info here: [Fail to start minikube with root-less podman #16919](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/16919)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the datetime configuration of my workstation was not configured properly causing the connection not taking place. After fixing my datetime settings all was normal and I could connect to the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

the problem started when I started minikube and stopping it. I was switching between docker-desktop and minikube. The solution was switching the context, so after I stopped minikube run this:

`$ kubectl config get-contexts` 
`$ kubectl config use-context docker-desktop`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't start the docker daemon. To fix that, using

```bash
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when the cluster I tried to connect to was turned off.

It's a good idea to confirm that your cluster is running.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple Container Runtime. I first made sure to pull all the required container images on the master node for the specified container runtime in this case containerd:

```
kubeadm config images pull --cri-socket /run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Then exported the admin.config with the following command as root:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

then

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.89.0/16 --upload-certs --control-plane-endpoint=k8sapi
```

After that, everything was ok in the cluster.